# How do I get my stored procedure to work inside my Visual Studio project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am using Visual Studio 2017 (Windows 10) and I have made an ASP.NET empty web application in C#.

In SQL Server Express, I wrote a stored procedure for edit, update and delete for my grid view. Earlier I have added strings for the edit, update and delete operations.

But for security reasons I now want a stored procedure to administrate my data. The stored procedure works correctly when I execute it in SSMS and all I have done so far is implemented the stored procedure into my code. But when I execute the code none changes can be made what so ever.

So the questions is how I should modify my code from here in Visual Studio in C# for the stored procedure to work when I execute my project?

`Default.aspx`

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestUsers.Default" %>
<link href="TestUsers.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="TestUsers.css">
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="~/orbitone.ico" />


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>ESDTESTERS</title>
<%--    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="20">--%>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="divC">
            
                <asp:GridView ID="gvTestUsers" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ShowFooter="True" DataKeyNames="tbl_users_key" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="True" OnRowCommand="gvTestUsers_RowCommand" OnRowEditing="gvTestUsers_RowEditing" OnRowCancelingEdit="gvTestUsers_RowCancelingEdit" 
                OnRowDeleting="gvTestUsers_RowDeleting" OnRowUpdating="gvTestUsers_RowUpdating" HorizontalAlign="Center"
                
                BackColor="#CCCCCC" BorderColor="#000000" BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="3px" CellPadding="5" OnSelectedIndexChanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="1470px" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black">

                 <%--Theme Properties--%>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="Black" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="Large" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Left" />
                <RowStyle BackColor="White" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#000099" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F1F1F1" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#808080" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#CAC9C9" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#383838" />

                <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="tbl_users_key">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("tbl_users_key") %>' runat="server" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
<%--                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" Text='<%# Eval("ID") %>' runat="server" />
                 </EditItemTemplate>--%>

             </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" Text='<%# Eval("Name") %>' runat="server" />
                 </EditItemTemplate>
                 <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtNamefooter" runat="server" />
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

             <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="CostCenter">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("CostCenter") %>' runat="server" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtCostCenter" Text='<%# Eval("CostCenter") %>' runat="server" />
                 </EditItemTemplate>
                 <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtCostCenterfooter" runat="server" />
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Employee">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Employee") %>' runat="server" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployee" Text='<%# Eval("Employee") %>' runat="server" />
                 </EditItemTemplate>
                 <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmployeefooter" runat="server" />
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

                    
              <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FootPlate">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("FootPlate") %>' runat="server" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtFootPlate" Text='<%# Eval("FootPlate") %>' runat="server" />
                 </EditItemTemplate>
                 <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtFootPlatefooter" runat="server" />
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="WirstCord">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("WirstCord") %>' runat="server" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtWirstCord" Text='<%# Eval("WirstCord") %>' runat="server" />
                 </EditItemTemplate>
                 <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtWirstCordfooter" runat="server" />
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Excluded">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Excluded") %>' runat="server" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtExcluded" Text='<%# Eval("Excluded") %>' runat="server" />
                 </EditItemTemplate>
                 <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtExcludedfooter" runat="server" />
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Comment">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                     <asp:Label Text='<%# Eval("Comment") %>' runat="server" />
                 </ItemTemplate>
                 <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtComment" Text='<%# Eval("Comment") %>' runat="server" />
                 </EditItemTemplate>
                 <FooterTemplate>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txtCommentfooter" runat="server" />
                 </FooterTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>

                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/GridImages/edit.png" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" ToolTip="Edit" Width="20px" Height="20px" /> 
                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/GridImages/delete.png" runat="server" CommandName="Delete" ToolTip="Delete" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/GridImages/save.png" runat="server" CommandName="Update" ToolTip="Update" Width="20px" Height="20px" /> 
                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/GridImages/cancel.png" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" ToolTip="Cancel" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ImageUrl="~/GridImages/add.png" runat="server" CommandName="AddNew" ToolTip="Add New" Width="20px" Height="20px" />
                        </FooterTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <br />

            <div style="margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; text-align: center;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblSuccessMessage" Text="" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" style="text-align:center" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="x-Large" />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblErrorMessage" Text="" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" style="text-align:center" Font-Bold="true" Font-Size="x-Large" />
            </div>

            

        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

`Default.aspx.cs`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;

namespace TestUsers
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
        //string connectionString = "Server=KNANTE800;Database=dataterm;Trusted_Connection=True";

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!IsPostBack)
            {
                PopulateGridView();
            }
        }

        void PopulateGridView()
        {
            DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

            using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                sqlCon.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * FROM TBL_USERS", sqlCon);
                sqlDa.Fill(dtbl);
            }

            if (dtbl.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gvTestUsers.DataSource = dtbl;
                gvTestUsers.DataBind();
            }
            else
            {
                dtbl.Rows.Add(dtbl.NewRow());
                gvTestUsers.DataSource = dtbl;
                gvTestUsers.DataBind();
                gvTestUsers.Rows[0].Cells.Clear();
                gvTestUsers.Rows[0].Cells.Add(new TableCell());
                gvTestUsers.Rows[0].Cells[0].ColumnSpan = dtbl.Columns.Count;
                gvTestUsers.Rows[0].Cells[0].Text = "No Data Found.";
                gvTestUsers.Rows[0].Cells[0].HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
            }
        }

        protected void gvTestUsers_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
                {
                    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

                    using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        sqlCon.Open();
                        //string query = "INSERT INTO TBL_USERS (Name,CostCenter,Employee,FootPlate,WirstCord,Excluded,Comment) VALUES (@Name,@CostCenter,@Employee,@FootPlate,@WirstCord,@Excluded,@Comment)";
                        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spEditTBL_USERS", sqlCon);
                        sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        // sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbl_users_key", (gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIDfooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", (gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNamefooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CostCenter", (gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCostCenterfooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee", (gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmployeefooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FootPlate", (gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFootPlatefooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WirstCord", (gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtWirstCordfooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Excluded", (gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtExcludedfooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", (gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCommentfooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                        sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        PopulateGridView();
                        lblSuccessMessage.Text = "New Changes Complete.";
                        lblErrorMessage.Text = "";
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "";
                lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        protected void gvTestUsers_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {
            gvTestUsers.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
            PopulateGridView();
        }

        protected void gvTestUsers_RowCancelingEdit(object sender, GridViewCancelEditEventArgs e)
        {
            gvTestUsers.EditIndex = -1;
            PopulateGridView();
        }

        protected void gvTestUsers_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

                using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    //string query = "DELETE FROM TBL_USERS WHERE tbl_users_key = @id";

                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spEditTBL_USERS", sqlCon);
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(gvTestUsers.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));
                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    PopulateGridView();
                    lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Selected Record Deleted.";
                    lblErrorMessage.Text = "";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "";
                lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }

        protected void gvTestUsers_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

                using (SqlConnection sqlCon = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    sqlCon.Open();
                    //string query = "UPDATE TBL_USERS SET Name=@Name,CostCenter=@CostCenter,Employee=@Employee,FootPlate=@FootPlate,WirstCord=@WirstCord,Excluded=@Excluded,Comment=@Comment WHERE tbl_users_key = @id";

                    SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand("spEditTBL_USERS", sqlCon);
                    sqlCmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    // sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tbl_users_key", (gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtIDfooter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());//
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CostCenter", (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCostCenter") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Employee", (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmployee") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FootPlate", (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFootPlate") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@WirstCord", (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtWirstCord") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Excluded", (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtExcluded") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Comment", (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtComment") as TextBox).Text.Trim());
                    sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", Convert.ToInt32(gvTestUsers.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString()));

                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    gvTestUsers.EditIndex = -1;
                    PopulateGridView();

                    lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Selected Record Updated.";
                    lblErrorMessage.Text = "";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "";
                lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Stored procedure:

```
-- =============================================
-- Author:      Måns Bodin
-- Create date: 2021-09.-23
-- Description: used for update ESD users
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spEditTBL_USERS] 
    @ID int = null, 
    @NAME varchar(255),
    @COSTCENTER varchar(10),
    @EMPLOYEE varchar(32),
    @FOOTPLATE bit,
    @WIRSTCORD bit,
    @EXCLUDED bit,
    @MODE smallint,
    @COMMENT varchar(255),
    @MSG varchar(255) OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @CHECK AS int

    SET @MSG = ''

    IF @MODE = 0 
    BEGIN
        SELECT @CHECK = COUNT(1) 
        FROM TBL_USERS 
        WHERE employee = @EMPLOYEE 

        IF @CHECK != 0
        BEGIN
            SET @MSG = 'Employee already exists in database.'
            RETURN 99
        END

        INSERT INTO TBL_USERS (Name, CostCenter, Employee, FootPlate, WIRSTCORD, Excluded, Comment) 
        VALUES (@NAME, @COSTCENTER, @EMPLOYEE, @FOOTPLATE, @WIRSTCORD, @EXCLUDED, @COMMENT)

        RETURN 0
    END

    IF @MODE = 1 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE TBL_USERS 
        SET Name = @NAME, 
            CostCenter = @COSTCENTER,
            Employee = @EMPLOYEE,
            FootPlate = @FOOTPLATE,
            WIRSTCORD = @WIRSTCORD,
            Excluded = @EXCLUDED,
            Comment = @COMMENT 
        WHERE tbl_users_key = @ID
            
        RETURN 9    
    END

    IF @MODE = 2 
    BEGIN
        DELETE FROM TBL_USERS 
        WHERE tbl_users_key = @ID

        RETURN 0
    END

    --  select * from TBL_USERS 
END
```

Comment: I'd install EF Core Power Tools, and use it to Reverse Engineer the DB into a context. EFCPT creates a separate context for stored procs, so you can use that to call your existing procs. 

Maybe eventually you'll get into using EF for at least read-only queries, mainly because every variation of sproc you'd have to write to serve the needs of a modern app is incredibly tedious and dull, or lead to sub optimal querying/crazy where clauses that cater for multiple predicates, and transferring too much data out of the db..

Comment: The way you're doing your data access here is sooo mind numbingly boilerplate boring that eventually you'll start looking for ways to make it easier, writing some kind of library that calls stored procedures.. then you'll tweak it and mess with it and extend it so maybe it returns first class objects, then some dynamism to parameters.. Then someone will point out that you've wasted months of your life writing some poor man's version of EF; I'm pointing out that you can shortcut it right now and get on with the interesting parts of coding..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I modified it like this and it worked very nicely for me!

RowUpdating:

```
    {

            try
            {
            //Parameters Set From Grid
                string tmpUsers_key = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtID") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string tmpName = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string tmpCostCenter = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCostCenter") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string tmpEmployee = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmployee") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string tmpFootPlate = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFootPlate") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string tmpWirstCord = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtWirstCord") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string tmpExcluded = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtExcluded") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string tmpComment = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtComment") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string tmpsMsg = "";

                //Call function for SP_UPDATE
                bool FuncResult = fcEditTBL_USERS(Convert.ToInt32(tmpUsers_key), tmpName, tmpCostCenter, tmpEmployee, Convert.ToBoolean(tmpFootPlate), Convert.ToBoolean(tmpWirstCord), Convert.ToBoolean(tmpExcluded), tmpComment,ref tmpsMsg,1);
                //Reload Page
                PopulateGridView();
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Selected Record Updated.";
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "";
                lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            }
    }
```

RowDeleting:

```
{

        try
        {

            {


                gvTestUsers.EditIndex = e.RowIndex;
                PopulateGridView();
               

                //Parameters for delete operation
                string dltUsers_key = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtID") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string dltName = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtName") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string dltCostCenter = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtCostCenter") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string dltEmployee = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtEmployee") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string dltFootPlate = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtFootPlate") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string dltWirstCord = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtWirstCord") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string dltExcluded = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtExcluded") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string dltComment = (gvTestUsers.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("txtComment") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
                string dltsMsg = "";


                //Call function for SP_Delete
                bool FuncDelete = fcEditTBL_USERS(Convert.ToInt32(dltUsers_key), dltName, dltCostCenter, dltEmployee, Convert.ToBoolean(dltFootPlate), Convert.ToBoolean(dltWirstCord), Convert.ToBoolean(dltExcluded), dltComment,ref dltsMsg,2);

                if (FuncDelete == false)
                {
                    lblErrorMessage.Text = dltsMsg;
                    lblSuccessMessage.Text = " ";
                    return;
                }



                PopulateGridView();
                lblSuccessMessage.Text = "Selected Record Deleted.";
                lblErrorMessage.Text = "";


                gvTestUsers.EditIndex = -1;


            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblSuccessMessage.Text = "";
            lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

RowCommand:

```
{
        try
        {
            if (e.CommandName.Equals("AddNew"))
            {


                int tbl_users_key = 0;

                TextBox myTxt;

                myTxt = ((TextBox)gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtNamefooter"));
                string Name;
                Name = myTxt.Text;

                string CostCenter;
                myTxt = ((TextBox)gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCostCenterfooter"));
                CostCenter = myTxt.Text;

                string Employee;
                myTxt = ((TextBox)gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtEmployeefooter"));
                Employee = myTxt.Text;

                Boolean  FootPlate;
                myTxt = ((TextBox)gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFootPlatefooter"));
              // string tmpFootPlate = (gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtFootPlate") as TextBox).Text.Trim();
               // boo Convert.ToBoolean(tmpFootPlate)
                FootPlate = Convert.ToBoolean(myTxt.Text);

                Boolean WirstCord;
                myTxt = ((TextBox)gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtWirstCordfooter"));
                WirstCord = Convert.ToBoolean(myTxt.Text);

                Boolean Excluded;
                myTxt = ((TextBox)gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtExcludedfooter"));
                Excluded = Convert.ToBoolean(myTxt.Text);

                string Comment;
                myTxt = ((TextBox)gvTestUsers.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCommentfooter"));
                Comment = myTxt.Text;


                string sMsg;

                sMsg = "";


               bool btest = fcEditTBL_USERS(tbl_users_key, Name, CostCenter, Employee, FootPlate, WirstCord, Excluded, Comment, ref sMsg,0);


                if (btest == false)
                {
                    lblErrorMessage.Text = sMsg;
                    lblSuccessMessage.Text = " ";
                    return;
                }

                PopulateGridView();

                lblSuccessMessage.Text = Name + " Was Added To Record.";
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            lblSuccessMessage.Text = "";
            lblErrorMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
```